# Merge dataframes of different sizes and simultaneously overwrite NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to combine two dataframes in Python of different sizes. These dataframes are loaded from Excel files. The first dataframe has many empty values containing NaN, and the second dataframe has the data to replace the NaN values in the first dataframe. The two dataframes are linked by the data in the first column, but are not in the same order.

I can successfully merge and organize the dataframes using merge(), but the resulting dataframe has extra columns because the NaN values were not overwritten. I can overwrite the NaN values with fillna(), but the resulting dataframe is out of order. Is there any way to perform this kind of merge that replaces NaN without separate operations that delete and reorder columns?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],'C':['X','Y','Z']})
df1
   A   B  C
0  1 NaN  X
1  2 NaN  Y
2  3 NaN  Z
df2=pd.DataFrame({'A':[3,1,2],'B':['U','V','W'],'D':[7,8,9]})
df2
   A  B  D
0  3  U  7
1  1  V  8
2  2  W  9
```

If I do:

```
df1.merge(df2,how='left',on='A',sort=True)
   A  B_x  C B_y  D
0  1  NaN  X   V  8
1  2  NaN  Y   W  9
2  3  NaN  Z   U  7
```

The data is in order but B has multiple instances.
If I do:

```
df1.fillna(df2)
   A  B  C
0  1  U  X
1  2  V  Y
2  3  W  Z
```

The data is out of order, but the NaN are replaced.

I want the output to be a dataframe which looks like this:

```
df3
   A  B  C  D
0  1  V  X  8
1  2  W  Y  9
2  3  U  Z  7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
df3=pd.concat([df1['C'],df2[['A','B','D']].sort_values('A').reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1).reindex(columns=['A','B','C','D'])
```

> Output:

```
df3
```

---

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1   V   X   8
1   2   W   Y   9
2   3   U   Z   7
```

**Explanation:**

`sort_values` ​​orders `df2` according to column `A`.

`reset_index (drop = True)` is necessary to concatenate the `DataFrame` in the correct order.

I use `concat` to join the column of `df1` `'C'` with `df2` whose `columns` are now in the correct order. Finally I use `reindex` to reposition the `columns` of the `DataFrame` `df3`.

You can see that the order of the DataFrame `df2` has not changed, since we have not used `inplace = True`.

Comment: There is a flaw in the logic here somewhere. Notice in the output that, while column B is now mapped correctly to column A, column C is not organized.

Comment: sorry, i fix the problem and upload the code!,
If you have any questions, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Elegant! I like it!

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any other questions about the code?

Comment: No, this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = dict(zip(df2.A,df2.B))
df1["B"] = df1["A"].map(d)
del df2["B"]
df1.merge(df2,how='left',on='A',sort=True)
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? It's normaly considered good form to explain your suggestions/answers. Code only answers can be surprisingly uninformative, even if they are technically correct. A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: This code appears to work. However, I am working with larger dataframes with many columns of NaN. Is there a way to generalize the mapping to multiple columns or do I have to do it individually? df1[2:3]=df1['A'].map(d) throws an error about the length of the keys.

Comment: df1[2:3] will slice the row(in this case third row) not column.Suppose df1 has another "D" column which consists of NaN,then `df1[["B","D"]] = mapping` where mapping is required to be same shape as  `df1[["B","D"]]`, i.e you can not  `df1[["B","D"]] = df1["A"].map(d)`